# Testing network equipment, TCP window size matters

Tags: networking, tcp

We are currently testing some network equipment (consumer routers with 1 Gbit/s ports) with Jpef 2.0. All kinds of connection parameters are tested: wired and wireless, different wireless standards, TCP/UDP, etc.

When not specifying a TCP window size, the performance is low (300 mbit/s). If you enter a high value, the throughput is much better (900 mbit/s). Google tells that Windows uses TCP Window Scaling, there is no "standard" TCP Window size.

What should we use as the TCP Window size in Jperf?

Comment: The only option allowed on Jperf is a fixed value?

Comment: Nope, you can manually choose a Window size.
edit: yes, it is one fixed value you can enter

Comment: As far I know it is an automatic algorithm, Windows adjust this value depending on the internet speed. I will try to find the theory behind it, but I think on your case you must set a value due to the speed of the network that you are testing...

Comment: Tried to find a good reference, but the best one that I found was [this](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPWindowSizeAdjustmentandFlowControl-2.htm). On my opinion Jperf leaves this value "open for edit" only because this way be a parameter important to test networks in some specific way. I mean, this should be a choice of the tester so you could find the best value for your network. I just reccomend you to read most of everything you could find about this and try to test different values until you reach the best one for you.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have enough information for now. I'm can't accept a comment as an answer, so could you post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, I will paste it as an asnwer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to find a good reference for you, but the best one that I found was [this](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPWindowSizeAdjustmentandFlowControl-2.htm). On my opinion Jperf leaves this value "open for edit" only because this way be a parameter important to test networks in some specific way. I mean, this should be a choice of the tester so you could find the best value for your the network you are testing and trying to improve or adjust. I just reccomend you to read most of everything you could find about this and try to test different values until you reach the best one for you.